# IndexError due to empty lines from input data

Tags: python

Below is a part of my python script, which reads data in daily automation in Linux system & print it in mail body & sends. my input file changes daily and it works perfectly if input file contains all strings (or) numarical values.

If the input file has empty string/value in any of rows, it throws IndexError and stops printing the data.

```
f = open('INPUTfile')
lines = f.readlines()
count=len(lines)
f.close()

body1="""

"""

z=0

while (z<count):
      test = lines[z]
      hello = test.split(',')
      a = hello[0:1]
      a1 = a[0]
      b = hello[1:2]
      b1 = b[0]
      c = hello[2:3]
      c1 = c[0]
      d = hello[3:4]
      d1 = d[0]
      e = hello[4:5]
      e1 = e[0]
      f = hello[5:6]
      f1 = f[0]
      g = hello[6:7]
      g1 = g[0]
      h = hello[7:8]
      h1 = h[0]
      i = hello[8:9]
      i1 = i[0]
      j = hello[9:10]
      j1 = j[0]
      k = hello[10:11]
      k1 = k[0]
      l = hello[11:12]
      l1 = l[0]
      m = hello[12:13]
      m1 = m[0]


      d1 = float(d[0])
      g1 = float(g[0])
      j1 = float(j[0])
      m1 = float(m[0])

      if all([d1 < 99.00, j1 < 99.00]):
              body1 = body1 + '<tr><td style="font-family:Calibri;"><b>' + a1 + '</b></td><td style="font-family:Calibri;">' + b1 + '</td></td><td style="font-family:Calibri;">' + c1 + '</td></td><td style="font-family:Calibri;color:red">' + str(round(d1,2)) + '</td></td><td style="font-family:Calibri;">' + e1 + '</td><td style="font-family:Calibri;">' + f1 + '</td></td><td style="font-family:Calibri;color:red">' + str(round(g1,2)) + '</td><td style="font-family:Calibri;">' + h1 + '</td><td style="font-family:Calibri;">' + i1 + '</td><td style="font-family:Calibri;">' + str(round(j1,2)) + '</td><td style="font-family:Calibri;">' + k1 + '</td><td style="font-family:Calibri;">' + l1 + '</td><td style="font-family:Calibri;">' + str(round(m1,2)) + '</td></tr>'

  z=z+1
```

My `inputfile`:

```
APPU1,2004423,2004417,99.9997,2847,2847,100,7600,7599,99.9846,1248,1248,99.9999
APPU2,,,
APPU3,2004333,2004329,99.9998,2848,2848,100,7593,7592,99.9842,1248,1247,99.9999
APPU4,2004020,2004016,99.9998,2849,2847,100,7596,7595,99.9853,1248,1247,99.9999
```

please suggest solution to print the data even if the rows in INPUT file contains null values.

Comment: use try - expect

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't understand use of while loop here.

Anyway what you need is an if statement at the starting of while loop.

```
while (z<count):
      test = lines[z]
      hello = test.split(',')
      if len(hello) < 14: # or whatever number of items required.
          z+=1
          continue
     #rest of your code goes here
```

If I were you, I would write the code like this.

```
with open('INPUTfile') as f:
    for i, line in enumerate(f):
        hello = line.split(',')
        #rest of the code.
```

Comment: Thanks Rahul, i used both of the ways, first method worked well (using while), and i am getting same error for second method, not sure why, i am beginner in Python. Could you please tell me the meaning of this line :if len(hello) < 14: (or) how it ignored the null content?

Comment: When you split a string it gives list. If your lisy is having len lesd than 14, hour while loop continues without error.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `try except` block in python.

```
try:
    <your logic here> or the code
except IndexError:
    pass # If IndexError is encountered, pass the control to the loop and continue from the next line
```

Use this code snippet and check if that solves the problem

```
for line in lines:
    try:
         test = line
              hello = test.split(',')
              a = hello[0:1]
              a1 = a[0]
              b = hello[1:2]
              b1 = b[0]
              c = hello[2:3]
              c1 = c[0]
              d = hello[3:4]
              d1 = d[0]
              e = hello[4:5]
              e1 = e[0]
              f = hello[5:6]
              f1 = f[0]
              g = hello[6:7]
              g1 = g[0]
              h = hello[7:8]
              h1 = h[0]
              i = hello[8:9]
              i1 = i[0]
              j = hello[9:10]
              j1 = j[0]
              k = hello[10:11]
              k1 = k[0]
              l = hello[11:12]
              l1 = l[0]
              m = hello[12:13]
              m1 = m[0]


              d1 = float(d[0])
              g1 = float(g[0])
              j1 = float(j[0])
              m1 = float(m[0])
    except IndexError:
        pass
```